# Treat Samsung Galaxy Tab 7'' as phone?

Tags: android

In out project we have a bunch of custom styles for all kind of device sizes and densities. One problem though is that Samsung Galaxy picks style from the `large-hdpi` folder and it looks ugly. The style in this folder really targets such devices as Nexus 7 or similar.

So the question is, how would I apply a specific style (I'm fine to create a separate style for this Tab) for this particular device? I know how to detect that our app runs on it, but not sure if it's possible to use a particular style in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: @323go It reports itself as HDPI - a long time known problem. Now the question is - how to make it pick styles from the mdpi folder

Comment: @323go Here I'm talking about Galaxy Tab I with codename sch-I800

Comment: did you get any more with this?